# Adding to a vector of pair

Tags: c++, vector, std-pair

I have a `vector` of `pair` like such:

```
vector<pair<string,double>> revenue;
```

I want to add a string and a double from a map like this:

```
revenue[i].first = "string";
revenue[i].second = map[i].second;
```

But since revenue isn't initialized, it comes up with an out of bounds error. So I tried using `vector::push_back` like this:

```
revenue.push_back("string",map[i].second);
```

But that says cannot take two arguments. So how can I add to this `vector` of `pair`?

Comment: So you don't have a vector pair but a pair vector, or vector of pairs. Once you understand this, you have solved your problem.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Use [`std::make_pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair):

```
revenue.push_back(std::make_pair("string",map[i].second));
```

Comment: What about emplace_back?

Comment: @Mr.WorshipMe, you can use it in C++11. See an answer below for an example. I'm not sure what you're asking though.

Comment: Would this approach differ in a constructor ? (eg. I have a class containing a vector of pairs and want to read from a two dimensional initializer_list. Where the inner one is supposed to be the pair. So I loop and `vec.push_back(make_pair ...)` like this)

Answer (score 44):

IMHO, a very nice solution is to use c++11 [emplace_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) function:

```
revenue.emplace_back("string", map[i].second);
```

It just creates a new element in place.

Answer (score 11):

```
revenue.pushback("string",map[i].second);
```

> But that says cannot take two arguments. So how can I add to this vector pair?

You're on the right path, but think about it; what does your vector hold?  It certainly doesn't hold a string and an int in one position, it holds a `Pair`.  So...

```
revenue.push_back( std::make_pair( "string", map[i].second ) );
```

Answer (score 11):

Or you can use initialize list:

```
revenue.push_back({"string", map[i].second});
```

Answer (score 6):

Read the following documentation:

http://cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/make_pair/

or

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair

I think that will help. Those sites are good resources for **C++**, though the latter seems to be the preferred reference these days.

Answer (score 4):

```
revenue.push_back(pair<string,double> ("String",map[i].second));
```

this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using another temporary pair:

```
pair<string,double> temp;
vector<pair<string,double>> revenue;

// Inside the loop
temp.first = "string";
temp.second = map[i].second;
revenue.push_back(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::make_pair`

```
revenue.push_back(std::make_pair("string",map[i].second));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `emplace_back` function is way better than any other method since it creates an object in-place of type `T` where `vector<T>`, whereas `push_back` expects an actual value from you.

```cpp
vector<pair<string,double>> revenue;

// make_pair function constructs a pair objects which is expected by push_back
revenue.push_back(make_pair("cash", 12.32));

// emplace_back passes the arguments to the constructor
// function and gets the constructed object to the referenced space
revenue.emplace_back("cash", 12.32);
```

Answer (score 0):

As many people suggested, you could use `std::make_pair`.

But I would like to point out another method of doing the same:

```
revenue.push_back({"string",map[i].second});
```

push_back() accepts a single parameter, so you could use "{}" to achieve this!